# IFCOUNTS and Not Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a CountS formula

```
=COUNTIFS(Master!F:F,"<>"&"90",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")
```

So I want to count all cells that contain "Building" in one column, EXCEPT if it contains the number 90 in column F

The thing is column F MUST be Text. So it contains Leters, Words, and (Text)Numbers. COUNTIFS does not seem to be able to pick up text-numbers, converting the whole column to numbers is not really an option.

How can I get CountS to see text-numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(Master!B:B,"*Buildings*")-COUNTIFS(Master!F:F,"90",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")
```

Comment: Alright. Lets expand my issue then: Column A must contain "Building", Column B Can NOT be 90, 70, or Exp, and Column C can Not be "FH" Is the best solution still along those lines?     =COUNTIF(Master!B:B,"*Buildings*")-COUNTIFS(Master!F:F,"90",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")-COUNTIFS(Master!F:F,"60",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")COUNTIFS(Master!F:F,"Exp",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")-COUNTIFS(Master!H:H,"FH",Master!B:B, "*Buildings*")?

Comment: Basically yes, you might need to put some brackets in there to control the calculation logic - but essentially the COUNTIF/COUNTIFS formulas are designed to work with the condition meeting a TRUE evaluation.

Comment: Ugh seems extremely unwieldy, but working is certainly better than not working. So thank you for the quick replies.

Comment: That's alright, the other option of course is to use a helper column that evaluates each row and then just use a COUNTIF formula on the helper column. Could even convert the data to a table and the formula in the helper column will be automatically generated for each row

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much data you have it might be better to use a different approach, e.g. assuming data in rows 2 to 100 you could use this "array formula" for your revised description as per comments

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("buildings",Master!B2:B100)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(Master!F2:F100,{"Exp","70,"90"},0)),IF(Master!C2:C100<>"FH",1))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>